# stop SMS propagation

Tags: android

I am trying to not to propagate an sms upon receiving like this

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        abortBroadcast();
        setResultData(null);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:priority = "100" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

but this is not working. I have been looking for a fix for days now. any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `android:priority` attribute on the `<intent-filter>`, not the `<receiver>`.

e.g

```
<intent-filter android:priority="9999" >
```

> Use this attribute only if you really need to impose a specific order
>   in which the broadcasts are received, or want to force Android to
>   prefer one activity over others. The value must be an integer, such as
>   "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. (The order applies only
>   to synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages.)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not add a comment on @ Christopher Orr's answer, it has to be pointed out that the priority must be between [-1000, 1000]. 9999 is too much.

> The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a
>   higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater
>   than -1000 and less than 1000.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html