# android abortBroadcast doesn't stop sms from being broadcasted

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

in my onReceive method I have this code:

```
if (from.equals(number)) {
    abortBroadcast();
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(in);
    Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Not from needed number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

where number = "29853" - number messages from which I wanna catch and not save in Inbox.

This code works correctly - if sms is from number the first Toast works and it prints the content of the message, if sms is not from number "Not from needed number" is printed. The problem is that abortBroadcast doesn't make its businness - the message from number is still in the Inbox of the phone although receiver's priority is 1000:

```
<receiver android:name=".service_classes.MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
                android:priority="1000" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

What's the problem - why doesn't abortBroadcast work?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919578/stop-sms-propagation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `abortBroadcast()` does not **DELETE** messages from the inbox, it is just **suppressing** the status bar notification. To delete the sms from the inbox, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: I think it does, but not on 4.4+ versions.

Answer (score 8):

move the `android:priority` to the intent-filter where it belongs.

```
 <intent-filter android:priority="9999999">
```

then you will more likely have priority and your canceling will work.
I have tested it and it does work.

Comment: what is the maximum value documented for priority ? did you calculate this value just by trial and error ?

Comment: The documented number is 1000. However everyone is using a number much higher, so basically the current situation is something like "first install first win".

Comment: According to the documentation: `The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.` So the maximum number exactly is 999.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Answer (score 4):

From Android 4.4 you cannot abort these broadcasts. Here's a link to the AOSP sources that show this:

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_opt_telephony/blob/d43b5b1ca91e0aac0c697546a5cb341ffa758e0b/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/ImsSMSDispatcher.java#L605

Comment: Certain features are just too dangerous to allow any app to take control over them, so this is the right behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this a while ago and it was working, I could reject some messages to show-up but this doesn't work now. I think android no longer lets user take all control over SMS_RECEIVED event.